# android how to call an override metod of other class

Tags: android, methods, overriding

In my application i have one activity and within that class i have an innerclass which class have some override method like **`onDraw()`**.
I want to call that **`onDraw()`** method in that activity or in different class.

Is it possible?
If possible give me some way to do that.

Here is my code bellow,

```
   public class MainClass extends Activity {
    @Override
           public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                   if (D)
                           Log.e(TAG, "+++ ON CREATE +++");

                   rot1 = new Rotate1(this);
                   rot1.onDraw(canvas);    }

//Innerclass
    public class Rotate1 extends ImageView {
    public Rotate1(Context context) {
                           super(context);

                           random = new Random();
                           paint = new Paint();
    }
    @Override
                   protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

                           super.onDraw(canvas);

                           height = this.getHeight();
                           width = this.getWidth();

                           // Log.d(tag, "Height of the canvas is = " + height);
                           // Log.d(tag, "Width of the canvas is = " + width);
                           //

                           final Bitmap bitmap = rollerDesk;
                           final Bitmap bitmap1 = mBitmap1;

                           ball2Rotate = new Canvas(mBitmap1);
    }
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: If you extend your innerclass with extend View class then its possible you can override its onDraw() method, What have you tried earlier. Post code.

Comment: I edited my c\question with code, just go through it

Answer (score 0):

From an inner class with a method name like onDraw that hides a method in the outer class (or one of its superclasses), you can use the following notation in the inner class method:

```
Outer.this.onDraw(args);
```

Answer (score 0):

you just write onDraw() the way you want it in the class that extends where ever the original onDraw is -- be careful as sometimes you have to call onDraw in the super-class

Answer (score 0):

Are overRidden method called by system internally on a particular event . so always call that event instead of overridden method . 
in your case call `CustomView.invalidate()` which will internally call onDraw() and refresh that view .